# Random Array Element

Tags: java, random, arraylist

I am trying to randomly choose 5 elements from an arraylist. For some reason, it always chooses 0 as the random element. Any help?? Here is my code that I have so far.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Rewards {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    String fileName = ("C:/Users/Jordan/Desktop/Proj5.txt");
    FileReader fin = new FileReader(fileName);
    Scanner src = new Scanner(fin);
    ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    src.useDelimiter(":");

    while (src.hasNext()) {
        lines.add(src.nextLine());
        System.out.println(src.next());
        // replace above line with array
    }
    String[] lineArray = new String[lines.size()];
    lines.toArray(lineArray);
    Random rand = new Random();
      for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
          int choice = rand.nextInt(lineArray.length);
          System.out.println("Random Winner is: " + choice);
         }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably because `lineArray` has zero length, since you're relying on that got your number range:

```
int choice = rand.nextInt(lineArray.length); // always 0 if lineArray is empty
```

The size of `lineArray` in turn depends on the size of `lines`, so that's probably empty too.

The size of `lines` in turn depends on the contents of `Proj5.txt`, so that is probably empty too.

Start with looking at the file, then debug (with the debugger of your IDE) your code.

Answer (score 0):

Prima facie, your code is correct.

Is the array empty ? Did you try printing its length ?

Instead of converting the `ArrayList` to an array, you can simply index it and get the elements using `lines.get(i)` and thus avoiding the extraneous step. Also, you can use `size()` to get the elements actually in the `ArrayList`; this can be used for setting the limit for the loop.